# alternative for uiimageview isanimating

Tags: uiimageview

i have a code which does some actions after UIImageView.isAnimating is false
but funny part is it never goes false its always in YES state.

" [isAnimating return is faulty for UIImageView for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144300/isanimating-return-is-faulty-for-uiimageview-for-iphone) "

people from this link see the same fault with IOS4.x
so can anyone please suggest any alternative to check whetheror not UIImageview is animating ?

Answer (score 3):

The following suggestions are not ideal, but I guess UIImageView should undergo improvements to become ideal in supporting animations. Anyways, here goes:

1. You can start a timer with the same interval as the animation length, and act on its expiry. (This solution is also suggested here: [How to use isAnimating in an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010477/how-to-use-isanimating-in-an-iphone-app))
2. You can create your animation with an NSTimer that changes the images by itself, completely abandoning UIImageView's animation. There's ready-made code for that here:
   ***www.modejong.com/iPhone/*** (under PNG Animation). This way you have total control over the animation - you can pause and resume it, call a delegate function on animation end, etc.

And for records sake, a similar question was asked here [iPhone : Best way to detect the end of UIImageView image sequence animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770997/iphone-best-way-to-detect-the-end-of-uiimageview-image-sequence-animation), although possible solutions were not iterated.

GL,

Oded.

p.s. Anyone know why I can't post the link above as a simple link? I get a "Sorry, posts can't contain that content." message...