# UIImageView animationDuration cache delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching, uiimageview

I wish to update a `UILabel` at the exact moment that a `UIImageView` animation stops playing.

My attempt at this has been to use -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateLabels) withObject:nil afterDelay:imageView.animationDuration];
```

Where `updateLabels` is the the method that updates the labels.

This does not work for the first couple of animations. However, it does work after the first 3  or 4 times it has been played.

I am using `imageNamed` to fill the `NSArray` that holds the images for the animations. And from my research I have noted that `imageNamed` caches the objects. So I am assuming that the lag on the first 3 or 4 runs is due to the lag off the cache.

Is there anyway to overcome this? (Preferably without changing from using `imageNamed`, as I said it is working fine on all other animation cycles after the first 3 or 4).

Answer (score 0):

Add `animationDidStop:` method that takes action when the animation stops.

```
  - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation*)animation finished:(BOOL)finished 
 {
    //Update your label
 }
```

Note don't forget to add `setDelegate` to `self` in `uiimageview.animation`

Comment: Thanks @Prince, but I am using UIImageView and do not have any CAAnimation. Can this still be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this: (not better realization, but)  // as example

in h.file:

```
UIImageView *im;
```

im .m - file:

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
   UIImage *firstIm = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];  // example pictures
   UIImage *secondIm = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
   im.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObject:firstIm, secondIm, nil];
   im.animationDuration = 1.0;
   im.animationRepeatCount = 4;
   [im startAnimating];
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabels) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void) updateLabels
{
   if (![im isAnimating]])
   {
      //Update your label
   }
}
```

it use -imageNamed  pictures, but in this case perform not better check of end animation.  May be it help you anyway.

Comment: Thanks @frankWhite, yes I had tried something similar using `isAnimating`. But it did not work as `isAnimating` was always in the `YES` state. Similar to [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583304/alternative-for-uiimageview-isanimating).